# Placing a Telerik Winforms StackLayoutPanel on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

What is the recommended way to place a RadElement instance on a Form?

Below is code from my form constructor.  My goal is that the form would show a scrollbar if sized small enough.  The code under #else involves standard Winforms controls and works fine.  The code under #if Telerik is equivalent, but does not function because I cannot add a StackLayoutPanel to the Controls collection of a form.  What would be perfect is if someone could reply with a modified version of the #if Telerik code below which places the StackLayoutPanel on the form such that the form's scrollbars appear when the form is sized smaller than the panel.

```
    AutoScroll = true;
#if Telerik
    StackLayoutPanel panel = new StackLayoutPanel();
    panel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    panel.AutoSize = true;
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    panel.Children.Add(new RadButtonElement());
    Controls.Add(panel);
#else
    FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
    panel.AutoSize = true;
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
    Controls.Add(panel);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the StackLayoutPanel in a panel control first:

```
var panelControl = new RadPanel();
panelControl.PanelElement.Children.Add(panel);
Controls.Add(panelControl);
```

Comment: Hi @Mike, In the form I added the StackLayoutPanel. Now how to add other controls in the stack panel?